# How to set the state of a past TaskInstance to success and continue the pipeline inside a airflow DAG?

Tags: python, airflow

I'm trying to make a DAG with params that can be triggered with a dag_id/task_id. The goal of this DAG is to set the state of the last executed task to "success" and to continue the pipeline from this point.

exemple of pipeline:

[image: DAG pipeline exemple]

In my dag I want to be able to set "run_that" to success and automatically run "run_them" as a result of the new state change.

Here is what I did from now:

```py
import airflow
from airflow.models import DagRun, TaskInstance, DagBag

from airflow.operators.dagrun_operator import TriggerDagRunOperator
from airflow.utils.trigger_rule import TriggerRule
from airflow.utils.state import State

from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator

import pendulum

from wrapper import ScriptLauncher, handleErrorSlack, handleErrorMail

from datetime import timedelta, datetime

default_args = {
  'owner': 'tozzi',
  'depends_on_past': False,
  'start_date': pendulum.datetime(2022, 12, 19, tz='Europe/Paris'),
  'retries': 0,
  'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=5),
  'xcom_push': True,
  'catchup': False,
  'params': {
    'dag_id': 'my_dag',
    'task_id': 'run_that',
  }
}

def last_exec(dag_id, task_id, session):
    task_instances = (
        session.query(TaskInstance)
        .filter(TaskInstance.dag_id == dag_id, TaskInstance.task_id == task_id)
        .all()
    )
    task_instances.sort(key=lambda x: x.execution_date, reverse=True)
    if task_instances:
        return task_instances[0]
    return None

def set_last_task_success(**kwargs):
    dag_id = kwargs['dag_id']
    task_id = kwargs['task_id']

    session = airflow.settings.Session()
    task_instance = last_exec(dag_id, task_id, session)
    
    if (task_instance is not None):
      task_instance.state = 'success'
      # task_instance = TaskInstance(task_id=task_id, execution_date=last_task_instance.execution_date)
      task_instance.run(session=session, ignore_ti_state=True, ignore_task_deps=True)
      session.commit()
      session.close()


doc_md=f"""## Set the given task_id to success of the given dag_id"""

# launched remotely
launcher = ScriptLauncher(default_args, "@once", 'set_task_to_success', ['airflow'], doc_md)

dag = launcher.dag;

set_to_success = PythonOperator(
    task_id='set_to_success',
    provide_context=True,
    python_callable=set_last_task_success,
    dag=dag,
    op_kwargs={
        'dag_id': '{{ params.dag_id }}',
        'task_id': '{{ params.task_id }}',
    }
)
```

The `task_instance.run(...)` call fail here with this error : "AttributeError: 'TaskInstance' object has no attribute 'task'", the state change is correctly working tho. What should I change so it rerun the "run_them" task when I change the state of the "run_that" task?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of Airflow 2.5.0 you can update the state of any existing task via the [Airflow REST API](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/stable-rest-api-ref.html#operation/patch_task_instance).

Comment: +1 Using the REST API or even the [Airflow Python Client](https://github.com/apache/airflow-client-python/blob/master/airflow_client/docs/TaskInstanceApi.md#patch_task_instance) is much more stable than trying to access the metadatabase explicitly. The underlying data model could change between versions and using the API/Client guarantees consistency of the interface.

Answer (score 1):

Using @TJaniF answer, I made this little reusable failure function task `on_failure_send_force_success_mail`, this function send a mail with a link to a custom API that call the patch task instance request using a get, it works as expected:

```py
def on_failure_send_force_success_mail(task_id):
    def send_mail(**context):
        result = requests.post('mailing_api_url', json={
            "from": "foobar@mail.com",
            "to": "tozzi@mail.com",
            "subject": "Airflow task failed",
            "html": f'Airflow task test failed: <a href="custom_api_url/script/{context["task_instance"].dag_id}/dag_runs/{context["dag_run"].run_id}/task_instances/{task_id}?new_state=success">click here</a>',
        })
    return send_mail

def run_this_func_failed(**context):
    raise Exception('FAILED')

def run_this_func(**context):
    print('COMPLETED')

run_that = PythonOperator(
    task_id='run_that',
    provide_context=True,
    python_callable=run_this_func_failed,
    dag=dag,
)

run_this = PythonOperator(
    task_id='run_this',
    provide_context=True,
    python_callable=run_this_func,
    trigger_rule="all_success",
    dag=dag,
)

on_failure = PythonOperator(
    task_id='on_failure',
    provide_context=True,
    python_callable=on_failure_send_force_success_mail('run_that'),
    trigger_rule="all_failed",
    dag=dag,
)

run_that >> on_failure
run_that >> run_this
```